# SonarQube Web Service API not displaying new_violations

Tags: sonarqube

I am writing a script for SonarQube. Right now, I don't know how to get new violations metrics from my project.

Here is my url:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/resources?resource=ATRT-TestManager-eclipse38-java7.group:parent&metrics=ncloc,classes,files,violations_density,class_complexity,comment_lines,comment_lines_density,new_violations,new_critical_violations,new_blocker_violations,blocker_violations,critical_violations,major_violations,minor_violations,functions,duplicated_blocks,duplicated_lines_density,open_issues,sqale_index&format=xml
```

At metrics, I specified new_violations as well as new_critical_violations and new_blocker_violations, however, these three do not pop up in the xml. All the other metrics do pop up. Is there something I have to add to make them show up, or are they currently broken? I am using the latest SonarQube which I have downloaded 2 days ago.

Comment: Could you intentionally inject a new issue and launch a new SonarQube analysis ? I guess you should start getting some results.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add **&includetrends=true** to the end of your URL so that these metrics show up.

Check the [docs](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation#api/resources) for more info.

Comment: Nope, still nothing.

Comment: Oh, wait, that worked: apparently, "yes" is nor valid value for that param. Weird.